# Updating Access from Excel

Tags: ms-access

We are updating Access from Excel using linked tables and am having trouble with specific fields that are conditional. The files are linked using a unique field and it updates an existing record if found or adds a new one if not found. In most cases, it is a field to field match from Excel to Access and works as expected, but we have a number of fields that are conditional. We've tried a number of different options and cannot get it to work.

Scenario 1: Access has two email fields, say Email1 and Email2. Excel has one email field and a mailing list field. If the mailing list field is Yes then the email address goes to email1, if it is no then the email address goes to email2.

Scenario 2: Access has four Y/N checkboxes, which display True or False in the data, call these fields A, B, C and D.  Excel has a single field with four possible entries "selection 1", "selection 2", "selection 3" and "Selection 4". If Excel is "selection 1" then A is true and B, C, D are false; if Excel is "selection 2" then B is true and A, C and D are false.

A snippet of the working code:

```
UPDATE AccessDB RIGHT JOIN [ExcelTbl]
ON [AccessDB].[MemberID] = [ExcelTbl].[MemberID]
SET [AccessDB].[MemberID] = [ExcelTbl].[MemberID],
[AccessDB].[First Name] = [ExcelTbl].[First Name],
[AccessDB].[Mid Initial] = [ExcelTbl].[Middle Initial],
[AccessDB].[Last Name] = [ExcelTbl].[Last Name],
```

When working on the scenarios above, we have tried If, Iif, Case and several other options and cannot get this to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Fields in query object cannot be conditional. The field is in the query or it isn't. The data populated into the field can be based on conditional expression. However, the conditional expressions are likely too long and complicated for query. Use VBA to construct an SQL statement and run the UPDATE with CurrentDb.Execute method.

Comment: Expressions for the 2 email fields are simple enough. `Email1=IIf(List="Yes", email, Null)` and `Email2=IIf(List="Yes", Null, email)`. However, the Yes/No fields may be too complicated.

Comment: Thank you, at least this allows me to save the query, none of the code I had tried would even save. Gives me something to work with.